# Optiplex 380 - Memory module 1Rx16 not compatible with 1Rx8 type?

Tags: memory, motherboard, dell-optiplex

Tried to do memory upgrade a Dell Optiplex 380 which had a single 2 GB memory module (1Rx8 PC3-10600U-9-11-A1 from hynix). 
1Rx8 should mean it's single rank with 8-bit wide data bus for each DRAM chip and yes, it has 8 chips in the module as expected.

The new memory I tried to insert was a Kingston KVR13N9S6/2 which is a 2GB module PC3-10600-CL9. However, this module has only 4 chips, meaning it is a be 1Rx16 type. This module does not work in the Optiplex 380, neither single nor in combination with the above.

Is the problem that this new module only has 4 chips? What is the problem with that? 4 x 16 bit wide = 64 bit, and 8 x 8bit = 64 bit, so they should look identical to the motherboard or not?

I do not understand why, and I cannot find any specs in any manual of Dell which says this should not work. Only RAM specs I can find is DDR3 10600 240pin unbuffered non-ECC. The Kingston module fits this perfectly but just won't work. I know that Dell computers are sort of picky about what RAM they'll accept but as long as the stated specs are kept, it should work, or not?

As a note, I upgraded my BIOS to A07 already, had no effect. I had A06 before which also did not work.

Anyone has any idea? Where would I find the "real" specs if the Dell manuals don't state them? Is there some hidden memory feature or property which I missed?

Comment: Outside of the machine not doing a POST, what audible sounds, do you hear?  Specific information on the CPU would be helpful.

Comment: Maybe the module is simply bad, test it in another computer.

Comment: @Ramhound, there are beeps of the pattern 1-3-2, and the diagnostics lights 1 and 3 are lit - according to Dell this means it is a memory compatibility issue.

Comment: @Techie007 - unfortunately the only PCs I have which fit this memory are Optiplex 380 ... and they all don't like that Kingston module it seems. If the module is bad - would I get the same beep code 1-3-2?

Comment: So is your question why doesn't this incompatible memory work or is it why is the memory incompatible?  I would assume its simply because of the age of the hardware in question.  My guess it has something to do with JEDEC support.

Comment: My question is why the memory is incompatible, as it seems to be.

Comment: When you say JEDEC support - you mean the RAM timing specifications? Curiously the only spec both memories state is CAS and both have 9. Neither of them list tRCP, tRP or tRAS on the module. Certainly there are other specifications which I have little knowledge about. So is that the problem? Specs being changed which aren't even communicatable to users as they are so highly technical? - Curiously, looking at the Kingston website on their "memory for specific systems" page, they state they no longer offer memory for Optiplex 380 systems ... what is so different on that Mobo?